# Swap Master Page used in View from a value selected in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a mvc app that currently is branded to one brand.

I want to add a user control that will hold a list of brands and when the user makes a selection the Master Page is swapped out, the styles will also be changed as the stlye link is held on the Master Page.

Has anyone done this before, is it possible and if so can anyone please show me some examples.

Answer (score 1):

[Rob Ashton's post](http://codeofrob.com/archive/2009/11/01/dynamically-switching-between-master-pages-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx) on selecting master pages at runtime should get you started.